# Increment A Progress Indicator Based On Dictionary Collection Size

Tags: c#, func

I am trying to figure a way to report on progress of looping through a dictionary with the following code:

```
int progressTracker = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Func<T>> methodPair in DicitionaryCollection)
{
progressTracker++;
progressTracker = (100 * progressTracker) / DicitionaryCollection.Count;
// do something with progress and collection contents
}
```

However this keeps returning the value, sort of jumps around in terms of value. Any thoughts?

Comment: use a diferent variable?

Comment: You are modifying your counter inside your loop, thereby invalidating your counter.

Comment: In fact, if you save your `progressTracker` as float or double and make the division as float or double division (not integer division), it won't jumps around some value but is increased very slowly. And of course as others answered, you should use different variables.

Comment: @KingKing that is not correct. No matter the type, that 'progress' will still jump. You are updating it as a counter, than resetting it to display your progress %. An example:
count = 1000
current = 99
What will happen: 
current ++ --> current = 100
current = (100* 100) / 1000 = 10.
next pass:
current ++ = 11

And the jump occurred. No matter the type.

Comment: @bastijn firstly, It depends on the initial value of `progressTracker`, if it's `1`, after increasing, it's `2`, if the `Count` is `150`, then `(100*2)/150` will become 1, the next loop, it's still `1`, so how do thing it can jump? my comment **lacks** one thing that it depends on some initial condition. BUT if you use correct double or float value, it will increase/jump with any initial condition.

Comment: Your theory is not valid in the general case, and hence is considered incorrect.  You must assume any count and a start of 0, your special situation is not common. Please,  don't go there, it will only confuse the user not directly understanding these fundamental concepts.

Comment: @bastijn my point here is if he used float and double *everything is double/float*, then it will increase slowly, but you said it's wrong. I don't encourage or make any confusion here. The code is simple enough, don't make it like as I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @kingking than read it again, and see your mistake. Program it, and see it clear. I never tried to say you couldn't understand, as your rating is an indication you should. Yet I think you might look too fast and not see your own mistake here. Would you program it like the OP but with a float or double? If that would go in the field?

Comment: @bastijn never, I'm not such stupid to do so. my comment **is just a talk**, some off-sided explanation, nothing more, and I'm sure if I mentioned that in my answer (if I had added), many downvotes will be given for that bad answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a different variable.

```
int currentProgress= 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Func<T>> methodPair in DicitionaryCollection)
{
  currentProgress++;
  int progressTracker = (100 * currentProgress) / DicitionaryCollection.Count;
  // do something with progress and collection contents
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a for loop - note the required cast to (double):

```
for (int i = 0; i < DicitionaryCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var methodPair = DicitionaryCollection[i];
    //... Do stuff
    var progressPercent = (i /(double)DicitionaryCollection.Count) * 100;
}
```

Comment: That is good. But I think that the OP should realize that he should use other variable..

Comment: I agree, the issue is not the foreach, it is the fact he is invalidating his variable used to keep progress.

Comment: using a foreach to essentially build a for-loop is a common anti-pattern, that should be avoided

Comment: I would remove the good part of my comment because you're indexing the dictionary in a wrong way.